# Lazy session fetching with Spring Redis

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I am testing the solution of storing session in spring boot redis. The problem is that in each request all session beans are fetched and deserialized. Is it possible to fetch the beans in lazy way? Meaning if there is no method invoked on session scoped bean than such object is not fetched from redis.

Comment: Can you add some more detail? Sample Beans and Spring Data config?

Comment: But in general look into `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` in JPA or use an Entity Graph to override the default fetch strategies in your beans

Comment: @BSB BSB Consider the fact that a class contains as fields 3 different injected session beans. Than I invoke a method in this class that only use one of mentioned session beans. The problem here is that spring fetch and deseialize all beans but i use only one of them.